# MySQL query to retrieve data from tables using inner join

Tags: mysql, join

These are the two tables    `Fruit` and `Fruit_types`.There is a    m:n relationship between the two tables so we have the third table  `fruit_type_fruit` which has the primary key from the above `two tables`. The tables look like this

```
Fruit
ID    NAME    
1    A
2    B
3    C

Fruit_type
ID    LABEL
1    CITRIC
2    DRUPES
3    UNCATALOGUED

Fruit_type_Fruit
Fruit_id    Fruit_type
1        1
1        2
1        3
2        1
3        3
```

Problem Statement: Some fruits even though they have a category(i.e label) get    label as    `Uncatalogued`.

For ex:-
        A gets the following labels :    Citric,    drupes and uncatalogued.

```
    B has    citric ,

    C has    Uncatalogued.
```

Now I need a query to delete all the records which have a suitable label but still have uncatalogued label too. 
In the above example

```
A record which is uncatalogued should be deleted and not

A    Citric and    Drupes neither

C    Uncatalogued.
```

Comment: in short you want only to delete records which is `Uncatalogued` only?

Comment: I want to delete records which have a valid label but are still mentioned as Uncatalogued .Example:    A -citric    A-Uncatalogued   C-Uncatalogued. SO A-Uncatalogued should be deleted as A already has a valid label citrus. C has only one label Uncatalogued and no other valid labels so C should not be deleted.

Comment: how it is defined in data structure that `A - Uncatalogued` ? the best  i see from data is that A-Citric, B-Drupes and C-Uncatalogued

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/437b6/1/0)

```
DELETE ftf
FROM fruit_type_fruit ftf
WHERE Fruit_type_ID = 3
AND Fruit_ID IN
    (
            SELECT *
            FROM (
                    SELECT DISTINCT Fruit_ID
                    FROM fruit_type_fruit f 
                    WHERE f.Fruit_type_ID = 3
             ) ss
            WHERE Fruit_ID IN (
                    SELECT *
                    FROM (
                    SELECT DISTINCT Fruit_ID
                    FROM fruit_type_fruit f 
                    WHERE f.Fruit_type_ID <> 3
             ) s)
  )
```